# How to generate MIDI of a drum score in Lilypond?

Tags: midi, drums, lilypond

I am beginning to experiment with Lilypond, trying to see the possibilities for writing drum scores / lead sheets.
So far I have found the `\drums` notation, as well as `\midi { }` command. However, when trying to add the MIDI block inside the drums block, it is reported as invalid.

I am using VSLilyPond extension on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that using the full syntax is better in this case:

```
\score {
    \new DrumStaff {
        \drummode {
            bd4 sn bd sn
        }
    }
    \layout { }
    \midi { }
}
```

This generates the MIDI file. I wonder if the same is possible with the `\drums` shorthand syntax.

Edit:
Thanks to the tip, this would be the short-hand syntax. Needing the \score envelope around, with the \midi instructions inside.

```
\score {
    \drums {
        bd sn bd sn
    }
    \midi { }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`\drums` is just a shorthand for `\context DrumStaff \drummode` which is almost like `\new DrumStaff \drummode` except that it won't start an unnamed `DrumStuff` if another already exists at the same point of time.  If you are doing drum rolls, you'll at least want the `Beat_performer` available since version 2.23.5 (which stresses the beats and thus subdivides the rolls), you'll want to wrap the music typeset in a separate score with `\midi` block into `\unfoldRepeats`, and you probably want to make use of the `\articulate` command from the include file `articulate.ly`.

That should probably cater for most keywords to look up in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! That's a bunch of new terminology to check out!